# How can I condense this "student grade" code into loops?

Tags: python

I have to write a program that accepts 5 scores and determines each scores equivalent letter grade. The results are to be printed in a tabular format.

I understand what the problem is asking for and all the other steps I'm not relaying since they do not pertain to my issue.

What I am having trouble figuring out is **how to condense my code into a loop(s) of some sort.**

I feel like what I have is very redundant and there should be a way to condense it.
Also, **I am not allowed to use lists for this problem.**

```
# Letter grade constants
A_SCORE = 90
B_SCORE = 80
C_SCORE = 70
D_SCORE = 60
# Gather scores from user
num1 = int(input("Enter score 1: "))
if num1 >= A_SCORE:
    letter1 = "A"
elif num1 >= B_SCORE:
    letter1 = "B"
elif num1 >= C_SCORE:
    letter1 = "C"
elif num1 >= D_SCORE:
    letter1 = "D"
else:
    letter1 = "F"
num2 = int(input("Enter score 2: "))
if num2 >= A_SCORE:
    letter2 = "A"
elif num2 >= B_SCORE:
    letter2 = "B"
elif num2 >= C_SCORE:
    letter2 = "C"
elif num2 >= D_SCORE:
    letter2 = "D"
else:
    letter2 = "F"
num3 = int(input("Enter score 3: "))
if num3 >= A_SCORE:
    letter3 = "A"
elif num3 >= B_SCORE:
    letter3 = "B"
elif num3 >= C_SCORE:
    letter3 = "C"
elif num3 >= D_SCORE:
    letter3 = "D"
else:
    letter3 = "F"
num4 = int(input("Enter score 4: "))
if num4 >= A_SCORE:
    letter4 = "A"
elif num4 >= B_SCORE:
    letter4 = "B"
elif num4 >= C_SCORE:
    letter4 = "C"
elif num4 >= D_SCORE:
    letter4 = "D"
else:
    letter4 = "F"
num5 = int(input("Enter score 5: "))
if num5 >= A_SCORE:
    letter5 = "A"
elif num5 >= B_SCORE:
    letter5 = "B"
elif num5 >= C_SCORE:
    letter5 = "C"
elif num5 >= D_SCORE:
    letter5 = "D"
else:
    letter5 = "F"

# Print results
print("score 1: \t\t" + str(num1) + "\t\t" + letter1)
print("score 2: \t\t" + str(num2) + "\t\t" + letter2)
print("score 3: \t\t" + str(num3) + "\t\t" + letter3)
print("score 4: \t\t" + str(num4) + "\t\t" + letter4)
print("score 5: \t\t" + str(num5) + "\t\t" + letter5)
```

Here's an example of what is displayed. It is in correct format, I have just excluded the tabular headings.

```
Enter score 1: 75
Enter score 2: 88
Enter score 3: 91
Enter score 4: 80
Enter score 5: 85

score 1:        75      C
score 2:        88      B
score 3:        91      A
score 4:        80      B
score 5:        85      B
```

Comment: When you find yourself using variables named `stuff1`, `stuff2`, `stuff3` ... `stuffN`, you should be able to make your code simpler and shorter (`N` times shorter!) with lists.

Comment: Why no lists? Is it homework constraint?

Comment: Consider using a [while loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm).

Comment: @Valentino Yes, it's constrained.

Comment: @Xukrao I have but I'm not quite sure how to set it up. I'll keep trying till I can figure it out either way.

Comment: Can you define functions? That's another avenue of attack, if you're allowed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the homework constraints not there in order to prevent lists altogether and work on it the hard way.

Best I can imagine shortening the code would be a function:

```
# Letter grade constants
A_SCORE = 90
B_SCORE = 80
C_SCORE = 70
D_SCORE = 60
# Gather scores from user

def getscore(num):
    if num >= A_SCORE:
        return "A"
    elif num >= B_SCORE:
        return "B"
    elif num >= C_SCORE:
        return "C"
    elif num >= D_SCORE:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

num1 = int(input("Enter score 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter score 2: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter score 3: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter score 4: "))
num5 = int(input("Enter score 5: "))

letter1 = getscore(num1)
letter2 = getscore(num2)
letter3 = getscore(num3)
letter4 = getscore(num4)
letter5 = getscore(num5)

# Print results
print("score 1: \t\t" + num1 + "\t\t" + letter1)
print("score 2: \t\t" + num2 + "\t\t" + letter2)
print("score 3: \t\t" + num3 + "\t\t" + letter3)
print("score 4: \t\t" + num4 + "\t\t" + letter4)
print("score 5: \t\t" + num5 + "\t\t" + letter5)
```

Note also there is no need to convert the ints to strings. The print function implicitly does this

Comment: Yes. My instructor likes us to learn how to solve things with more difficulty, though there are easier ways to do so, so that we're not reliant on shortcut methods while in his class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a textbook case for using a loop. Whenever you find yourself writing repetitive code full of commands, changing only minor details each time, see if you can use a loop:

```
A_SCORE = 90
B_SCORE = 80
C_SCORE = 70
D_SCORE = 60

scores = []
grades = []

for n in range(1, 6):
    grade = int(input("Enter score {}: ".format(n)))
    grades.append(grade)

    if grade >= A_SCORE:
        scores.append('A')
    elif grade >= B_SCORE:
        scores.append('B')
    elif grade >= C_SCORE:
        scores.append('C')
    elif grade >= D_SCORE:
        scores.append('D')
    else:
        scores.append('F')

for n, (score, grade) in enumerate(zip(scores, grades), 1):
    print("score {}: \t\t".format(n) + str(grade) + "\t\t" + score)
```

Output:

```
Enter score 1: 75
Enter score 2: 88
Enter score 3: 91
Enter score 4: 80
Enter score 5: 85
score 1:        75      C
score 2:        88      B
score 3:        91      A
score 4:        80      B
score 5:        85      B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bisect` module to get the grades. Here, the `get_score` will take a number grade and returns the letter grade.

```
from bisect import bisect
def get_score(A):
    i = bisect([60, 70, 80, 90], A)
    return 'FDCBA'[i]

mm = []
for i in range(5):
    mm += [input('Enter score {}: '.format(i))]

for m in mm:
    print('score {}:  {}   {}'.format(i, m, get_score(int(m))))

#Outputs
Enter score 0: 75
Enter score 1: 88
Enter score 2: 91
Enter score 3: 80
Enter score 4: 85
score 4:  75   C
score 4:  88   B
score 4:  91   A
score 4:  80   B
score 4:  85   B
```